# Combine svlogd logs from different runit services

Tags: logs, node.js, runit

I want to run a Node.js app with multiple Node processes running the exact same code.  I'm using [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) to start and manage the Node processes, because it has [good Chef support](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/runit).  To illustrate the set up, imagine I'm running 2 runit service directories:

**/etc/sv/test-1/run**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo running test 1
sleep 9999
```

**/etc/sv/test-2/run**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo running test 2
sleep 9999
```

(Where `echo` and `sleep` are test placeholders for running the actual Node app.)

This works great...  except by default `runit`'s `svlogd` program wants to put each service's logs in separate directories.  The problem is, I don't want to have to look in multiple places to see all the log entries for one application.

My first attempt at getting `svlogd` to write to the same log file looks like this:

**/etc/sv/test-1/log/run**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -tt /var/log/test
```

**/etc/sv/test-2/log/run**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -tt /var/log/test
```

Only this doesn't work.  Whichever log service starts first, runs fine.  The log service that starts second does not run because it is locked out by the other log service.  To illustrate:

```
$ sudo /etc/service/test-2/log/run
svlogd: warning: unable to lock directory: /var/log/test: temporary failure
svlogd: fatal: no functional log directories.
```

---

What's a better way to set this up?  How can I have one place to look to see all the log entries from different `runit` services that are running the same code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use 'logger' to syslog

If you're happy with syslog, then use `logger` instead of `svlogd`.  The whole point of having a runscript for your logger is that you can run whatever program you like to do the logging.

#### /etc/sv/test-1/log/run

```
#!/bin/sh
exec logger -i -p daemon.notice -t my_service
```

.

### Merge when viewed

Another good idea is to just let the logs go to separate places and then use a script that merges the files together as you view them.  For example, with the timestamps from `svlogd` you can just

```
cat /var/log/test/*/current | sort | less
```

There are other robust tools out there which can view multiple log files simultaneously, like [multitail](http://www.tecmint.com/view-multiple-files-in-linux/)

Comment: Nice. Much cleaner. I also like your suggestion to use multitail.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `svlogd` doesn't support combining logs into a single file.  However, it does support logging to a socket.  My workaround is to instruct `svlogd` to forward log entries over UDP to the running [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) instance.

**/etc/sv/test-1/log/run**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -tt /var/log/test/1
```

**/var/log/test/1/config**

```
ptest-1: 
U127.0.0.1
```

**/etc/sv/test-2/log/run**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -tt /var/log/test/2
```

**/var/log/test/2/config**

```
ptest-2: 
U127.0.0.1
```

From there, it's just a matter of configuring rsyslog to do what you want.